# Should I new-up a new delegate or just add the method to an event?

Tags: c#

I don't understand what the difference between these 2 variations are.  What is the pros/cons of each approach?

```
1.  a.MyEvent += new MyClass.MyEventDelegate(FireEvent);

2.  a.MyEvent += FireEvent;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one works in all versions of C# while the second only works on 2.0 and above. If you need your to compile you code with C# 1.0 compiler, go with the first one; otherwise, I'd use the more concise version. The generated code should be identical in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Really it's syntactical sugar, the compiler will interpret the code and make the Delegates for you.