# Is there a difference between the following ways to register to event

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

I would like to register to some event. The following ways works:

```
public void AddOptionAsListner(OptionElement option)
    {
        option.Selected += onOptionSelectedChanged;
    }

public void AddOptionAsListner(OptionElement option)
    {
        option.Selected += new EventHandler(onOptionSelectedChanged);
    }
```

Is there a difference or that this is just different syntax for the same thing?

Comment: no difference. 
my 0.02c, same is also true while you unregister the event.

Comment: @Mehrdad - You can at least have the decency to give a link to the duplicate

Comment: @Elad: Actually I tried to find it without success. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247206/1247212#1247212

Comment: OK, thanks for the link. I think the answers provided here were a little more elaborated. Otherwise I would have deleted the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Same - No diff. The compiler infers the type of delegate and does it auto-magically for you. Syntactic sugar to make your life a bit easier

Just checked with C#-in depth. This feature is called "**Method group conversions**" ; added in C#2.0

e.g. from the book

```
static void MyMethod() { ... }
static void MyMethod( object sender, EventArgs e) {...}

static void Main() {
    ThreadStart x = MyMethod;  // binds to first overload
    EventHandler y = MyMethod; // binds to second overload
}
```

If I open this up in reflector, you'd see that the compiler just created the delegate instances of the right type for you, behind the scenes of course.

```
    L_0000: ldnull 
    L_0001: ldftn void CS.Temp.Program::MyMethod()
    L_0007: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Threading.ThreadStart::.ctor(object, native int)
    L_000c: pop 
    L_000d: ldnull 
    L_000e: ldftn void CS.Temp.Program::MyMethod(object, class [mscorlib]System.EventArgs)
    L_0014: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.EventHandler::.ctor(object, native int)
    L_0019: pop
```

Comment: The latter is an old sintax that was required on 1.1, if my memory serves. Or maybe it was 2.0. But now the compiler does the trick by itself.

Comment: Right you are.. Was in the process of checking back with the ref book :) The 2.0+ compiler is now smart enough convert a method/method group to the right type of delegate

Answer (score 3):

It's the same thing, the new EventHandler() is just redundant.

You don't need to explicitly create a delegate for an event handler.

Comment: The small difference is that the fist one won't compile in c# 1.0.

Comment: Good point, but since the question was tagged C#3.0, I didn't think to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the runtime is concerned there is no difference. The compiler sees them as *slightly* different in that it must infer the signature for the delegate (your event handling method) based on the signature of the event itself while in the second it is told what the signature should be.

The second signature is the one that is automatically generated for you by Visual Studio if you use the "automatic" (i.e., the "tab, tab" sequence) when subscribing to an event.